# Scaling up SVG is blurry only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

When I scale up an SVG it is blurry only in Chrome, it is perfect in Firefox and almost perfect in IE. I have tried to achieve the same effect with SMIL but it is still blurred.

Codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/MrThunder/pen/pJeJEm)

I have been searching for a fix but I have been unable to find one.

Thanks

CSS:

```
.svg-container{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: scaling 4s linear  infinite alternate forwards;
  animation: scaling 4s linear infinite alternate forwards;
   transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);

}
@-webkit-keyframes scaling {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
    }
}

@keyframes scaling {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="svg-container">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="644px" height="474px" viewBox="0 0 644 474" style="enable-background:new 0 0 644 474;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {fill: #22B573;stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 23;stroke-miterlimit: 10;}            
        .st1 {fill: #39B54A;stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 6;stroke-miterlimit: 10;}            
        .st2 {fill: #00723D;stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 6;stroke-miterlimit: 10;}
        </style>
        <circle class="st2" cx="381.307" cy="280.325" r="135.276" />
        <circle class="st1" cx="381.307" cy="280.325" r="112.99" />
        <circle class="st0" cx="381.307" cy="280.325" r="67.177" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Not specific to svg, see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=413636.

Comment: I see, very annoying as it defeats the basic purpose of scalable vector graphics. Tack så mycket Eric.

Comment: One workaround is animating width and height instead, see http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css/animations/zoom-transform.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this looks now:

```css
.svg-container{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: scaling 4s linear  infinite alternate forwards;
  animation: scaling 4s linear infinite alternate forwards;
   transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);

}
@-webkit-keyframes scaling {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
    }
}

@keyframes scaling {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(16, 16) translateZ(0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
            transform: scale(0.75,0.75) translateZ(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="644px" height="474px" viewBox="0 0 644 474" style="enable-background:new 0 0 644 474;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {fill: #22B573;stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 23;stroke-miterlimit: 10;}            
        .st1 {fill: #39B54A;stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 6;stroke-miterlimit: 10;}            
        .st2 {fill: #00723D;stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 6;stroke-miterlimit: 10;}
        </style>
        <circle class="st2" cx="381.307" cy="280.325" r="135.276" />
        <circle class="st1" cx="381.307" cy="280.325" r="112.99" />
        <circle class="st0" cx="381.307" cy="280.325" r="67.177" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still pixelated when zoomed in on chrome if you test it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an explicit width and height pixel value as @Erik Dahlstöm [suggested](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css/animations/zoom-transform.html). I already had a width, but setting an explicit height was all I needed.

[image: before]

vs

[image: after]